# Leaflet map.locate, very long response time

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm using leafletknn to search the nearest geojson element from the user location. I add a map.locate method that zoom to the user location. The response time is longer than when I directly use it... why ?

```
var  gjLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData);  

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos)
    {   
        var res = leafletKnn(gjLayer).nearest(
            [pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude], 1);

        if (res.length) {
            document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 
                'The nearest element is at ' + 
                res[0].layer.feature.properties.cityname;

            map.locate({setView: true});
        } else {
            document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'error';
        }
    });     
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The increased response time is likely due to the delay waiting for getcurrentposition to retrieve the device position.  If using on a mobile device there could be a delay while the device attempts to retrieve a position from GPS, or fallbacks to Wifi Geolocation. On a desktop computer this delay could be while the browser queries a Geolocation API to retrieve a location based on your IP address.

To investigate try inserting some Debug statements to log the time to the console and find out whether leafletKnn really is taking longer, or if it's the geolocation delay:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
 var _locateTime, _completeTime
var _startTime = Date.now();
console.log('Requesting Geolocation ' + _startTime); 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos)
{   
    _locateTime = Date.now();
    console.log("location obtained " + _locateTime);
    var res = leafletKnn(gjLayer).nearest(
        [pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude], 1);

    if (res.length) {
        document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 
            'The nearest element is at ' + 
            res[0].layer.feature.properties.cityname;

        map.locate({setView: true});
        _completeTime = Date.now();
        console.log("Completed time : " + _completeTime + " elapsed time (s): " + (_startTime- _completeTime)/1000);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'error';
    }
});     
};
```

Comment: Console return me that "dateTime is not defined", how should I initialize it ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, should also be Date.now() like the others - note though that method is only supported in modern browsers (IE8+) so should be removed from any production code.

Comment: It works. You also forgot a "t" at the fourth line (startTime)

Comment: Great, so how does that work - do you see the delay with the geolocate or the nearest neighbour? If it's the former then there isn't much you could do, other than perhaps [add a timeout](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_options_interface)

Comment: Yes, in my case the elapsed time is about -1,538